# How to customize or remove the SilverLight Update alert box?

Tags: silverlight

We recently added a small silverlight client that loads on every page load.

However for the visitors who for some reason don`t want to upgrade their silverlight version they are seeing this annoying message on every single page load:
[image]

From where is this alert triggered and how can I stop it from being triggered? I`ve looked in the silverlight.js file but can`t find it.

Following is the code where the Silverlight app is embeded:

```
            <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://$CommonHelps.GetSiteInfoByDomain().ContentDomainJavascript/Silverlight.js"></script> 
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="5" height="5" >
                <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/AppLaunch.Bloc.Frontend.SilverLight.UserOnlineClient.xap"/>
                <param name="onError" value="AppLaunch.Chatbar.onSilverlightError" />
                <param name="background" value="white" />
                <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
                <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" target="_blank">
                    Install silverlight to chat with your friends
                </a>
            </object>
            <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame"></iframe>
        </div>
        <p id="UserOnlineClientConnectionClientEx"></p>
```

Comment: Not updating Silverlight is a security risk, you should tell your users to either update, or get their passwords stolen. That should get them on other thoughts. ;)

Comment: If I only can find where the alert is triggered I can customize it to a less annoying message and print a "please upgrade" message in the document instead. The same way as you see the "Install silverlight to chat with your friends" message when user don`t have silverlight installed.

Comment: +1, I'm having this same problem.  I'd like to disable it or change the upgrade link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Heuer blogged the answer to this a while ago in his [silverlight 3 beta install guidance](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/23/silverlight-3-beta-install-guidance.aspx) blog post.  You need to make sure you have minRuntimeVersion with a minimum version, autoUpgrade param set to false, and onerror param set to a javascript function, such as below:

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40307.0" /><param name="autoUpgrade" value="false" /><param name="onerror" value="pluginError" />
```

You then need the js error function, called pluginError above to check for errorCode 8001.  Set what you want the user to see within that if statement.  **This stops the popup!**